# Defined function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(2xy) + f(f(x + y)) + f(x + y) = xf(y) + yf(x)$

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

Defined function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies
$$f(2xy) + f(f(x + y)) + f(x + y) = xf(y) + yf(x)$$
for any real numbers $x$ and $y$. Determine the sum of all values $|f(48)|$ which possible.

My working:
$$f(2xy) + f(f(x + y)) + f(x + y) = xf(y) + yf(x)$$
Assume: $y=-x$
$$f(2x^2) + f(f(0)) + f(0) = xf(-x) -xf(x)$$
$$2f(x^2) + f(f(0)) + f(0) = -xf(x) -xf(x)$$
$$2f(x^2) + f(f(0)) + f(0) = -2xf(x)$$
$$2f(x^2) + f(f(0)) + f(0) = -2f(x^2)$$
$$f(f(0)) + f(0) = -2f(x^2)-2f(x^2)$$
$$f(f(0)) + f(0) = -4f(x^2)$$

so, I still have doubts about my work with the process. how?

Comment: $2x(-x)=-2x^2$. And there is no reason to take either the $2$ nor the minus sign out of the function.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Why does $f(2x^2)=2f(x^2)$?  And why is it $f(2x^2)$ instead of  $f(-2x^2)$? Why does $xf(-x)=-xf(x)$?

Comment: It's often a good idea to start by trying to find simple functions which satisfy the given equation. For instance, the constant function $0$ works.  Can you find other simple functions that work?

Answer (score 6):

Let $a=f(0)$ and plug $y=0$ in the starting equation. We get $$f(f(x)) + f(x) = ax-a$$ for all $x$ and thus with replacing $x$ with $x+y$ in last equation we get $$f(2xy) + a(x+y)-a = xf(y) + yf(x)$$

Now let $b= f(1/2)$ and put $y=1/2$ and we get $$2f(x) +a(2x-1) = 2xb +f(x)$$ so $f$ is some linear function and now should be easy to finish the task.